# How to display an array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I have a csv file that I converted to array using the split(",") method.
Now I'm trying to display this data as a table/grid using React but having hard time, how can I do so and what's the best practice?

My csv looks like this:

```
restaurant, amount, McDonalds, 3$, StarBucks, 2.5$, Wendy's, 1$
```

Edit: that's my code:

```js
import * as React from "react"
import {rawData} from "./raw.data"

export class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    csv: rawData,
    //Here I set my data to be an array from the csv file
    data: rawData.replace(/\n/g, ",").split(",")

  }

  render() {
    const {csv, data} = this.state
    return
      
      <div> I want to add my table from Data here </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: And how does your code look like? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How do you try? Give your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
render() {
    const {csv, data} = this.state
    return(
    <div> {data.map(item => <div> {item} </div>} </div>
   )
}
```

version 2

```
render() {
const {data} = this.state
var t = data.filter(item => item != "restuarant" || "amount");
var amt;
var rest;
var newVals = t.map(function(item, index) {
  if(index % 2 == 0) rest = item;
  else amt = item;
  if(index % 2 ==0 &&  index > 0){
  return {
    amount: this.amt,
    restaraunt: this.rest,
    key: index,
  }
}
});
 return (
  <div>
   <h1> Restraunts and Amount</h1>
   <div> {newVals.map(item =>  <div> {item.restaraunt} {item.amount} </div> } </div>  
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! if I want the restaurants to be in one column and the prices in the other?

Comment: do we need to initialize amount, restaurant and key in the return statement of the mapping function? I got an error says it's undefined

Comment: what exactly is undefined

Comment: Thank you Omar, I changed and added another function to my code and it works now! I needed a better understanding of React and its inheritance in order to solve this.